# what is difference between syntax I(0,1) and I(1,0) in USB standard?

Tags: usb, protocols

In the `USB: smart card CCID specification's part7`, there are examples for TPDU level. for T=1 protocol the syntax `I(i,j)` is used. I can't understand the difference between `I(0,1) and I(1,0)`. What does exactly this syntax mean?

Answer (score 0):

I see that in the protocol T=1 the information blocks are denoted by notation I(i,j) where `i` is the `sequence number` of blocks sent and encoded by one bit, while the `j` is the `M bit of the PCB field` that shows the `chaining state`.